# Too many re-renders when setting state

Tags: reactjs

Seems like this is a common issue in React, so apologies for asking this question again. I have a `ParentComponent` that contains a map with state. The map needs to have state because you can update its contents are meant to be updated. When I try to set the state of the map, I get an error stating too many re-renders. I've even tried using the useEffect hook, but I can't figure out the issue. Here's what I have:

```
const ParentComponent = ({show, onCloseModalButton}) => {
    const [resorts, setResorts] = React.useState(new Map())
    
    const tmpResorts = new Map(resorts)
    tmpResorts.set("Keystone", [39.6069742, -105.97011])
    tmpResorts.set("Breckenridge", [39.4808, -106.0676])
    tmpResorts.set("Vail", [39.6061, -106.3550])
    tmpResorts.set("Crested Butte", [38.8991, -106.9658])
    tmpResorts.set("Winter Park", [39.8841, -105.7627])
    tmpResorts.set("Copper Mountain", [39.5022, -106.1497])
    setResorts(tmpResorts)
    ...
```

Here's what I've tried, to no avail:

```
const ParentComponent = ({show, onCloseModalButton}) => {
    const [resorts, setResorts] = React.useState(new Map())
    
    const tmpResorts = new Map(resorts)
    React.useEffect(() => {
        tmpResorts.set("Keystone", [39.6069742, -105.97011])
        tmpResorts.set("Breckenridge", [39.4808, -106.0676])
        tmpResorts.set("Vail", [39.6061, -106.3550])
        tmpResorts.set("Crested Butte", [38.8991, -106.9658])
        tmpResorts.set("Winter Park", [39.8841, -105.7627])
        tmpResorts.set("Copper Mountain", [39.5022, -106.1497])
        setResorts(tmpResorts)
    }, [tmpResorts])
    ...
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: "_a common issue in React_" - really a common issue with developers who use React. Anyway, `tmpResorts` will be created each time the component renders. Meaning the dependency changes every time, causing the re-render. Move the `tmpResorts` declaration into `useEffect` and remove the dependency.

Comment: Have you tried setting the map `useState(new Map(['Keystone', [39, -105]])` that way, you dont need to use an effect, or a temporary value that causes a re-render. If the values are loaded `async`, then you can `setResorts` in the hook

Comment: @RandyCasburn fair, that's essentially what i meant, just bad wording. i just tried that and i'm no longer getting the error, message, but i'm getting 100s of error logs per second in the console. something still isn't playing nice

Comment: @SterlingArcher just tried switching it to `const [resorts, setResorts] = React.useState(new Map(['Keystone', [39.6069742, -105.97011]]))` and now i'm getting this error message `Uncaught TypeError: Iterator value Keystone is not an entry object`

Comment: I agree with @RandyCasburn.  You create a new `tmpResorts` which you modify and then set that value to the `resorts` state, which causes a new render which creates a new `tempResorts` -- this turns into updating state over and over.  Another solution may be to use a `useRef` to store the value of tmpResorts.

Comment: @RandyCasburn just realized my API key got temporarily blocked because one my "solutions" accidentally sent too many requests to the weather api. i'll check back later tomorrow and see if it works or not. sounds like your solution should fix it though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `tmpResorts` from useEffect Dependency array will fix it:

```
const [resorts, setResorts] = useState(new Map());
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('called');
    const tmpResorts = new Map(resorts);
    tmpResorts.set('Keystone', [39.6069742, -105.97011]);
    tmpResorts.set('Breckenridge', [39.4808, -106.0676]);
    tmpResorts.set('Vail', [39.6061, -106.355]);
    tmpResorts.set('Crested Butte', [38.8991, -106.9658]);
    tmpResorts.set('Winter Park', [39.8841, -105.7627]);
    tmpResorts.set('Copper Mountain', [39.5022, -106.1497]);
    setResorts(tmpResorts);
  }, []);
```